# Use the index in naming variables during a cycle C++

Tags: c++, variables, dynamic, cycle

I need a tip in creating a C++ utility.
I'm implementening an optimization algorithm, and at a certain step, I would need to create as much new variables as the iterations of a cycle.
There's some code that would explain it better:

```
for(int i=1;i<112;i++){
   struct nodo n_2i[111-i];           
}
```

The structure nodo is defined as:

```
struct nodo{
  int last_prod;
  int last_slot;
  float Z_L;
  float Z_U;
  float g;
  bool fathomed;
};
```

I would like the names of the new variables (arrays of structures) to be n_21,n_22,n_23,...etc.
How can I handle that?

Comment: You cannot generate variable names dynamically. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968725/change-variable-name-with-a-loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need the name to be n_21. you can use a vector of vector.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<vector<struct nodo> > n;
    for(int i=1;i<112;i++){
        n.push_back(vector<struct nodo>(111-i));       
    }
    // you can use n[0] ... n[111] now
}
```

Comment: I think he only needs a one-dimensional vector.

Comment: I think that's what I need. If I get it straight, now `n[0],n[1]...` refer to vectors. But how can I now access the members of `n[i]`?

Comment: @Ade that doesn't work. the `(111-i)`code after the push_back stays for the size of the new elements?

Comment: @MarcoBi Yes. Note that in the `for` loop, the last pushed element is `n[i-1]`, and it has `111-i` elements. So you can use `n[i-1][0]` ... `n[i-1][110-i]`

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare new variable names during run-time. You're best off creating a `std::vector` of the variables.

Comment: Though true, I don't think that's what the OP is asking. I think he wants to create a set of arrays, each array with a different name: `n_2i` for each i in `[1,112)`

Comment: Good thing about `std::vector` is you can `reserve()` the amount of space needed ahead of use.

Comment: @amit which you can't. What's the name of an array? Certainly not a key in a map...

Answer (score 1):

Once the code is compiled, variable names are no longer present. At compile time the loop is a single construct (unless/until it is unrolled), and at that point it does not make sense to have different names referring to the same compile time element (*the* variable). The whole question makes little sense, I would advise you to provide a single variable with a good name that need not change for each iteration.

Also, c++ has no variable sized arrays, that is a C99 construct that only some compilers accept, so you might want to get rid of that and use a single array of the greatest size you will need together with a constant initialized in each iteration that will control how many of the positions of the array are valid. If you don't have an upper bound on the size, you can dynamically allocate the memory before entering the loop and release after completing the last iteration. (to avoid the expense of reallocating with each iteration.

That is, unless you need to check the previous step results...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a `std::map<string,struct nodo*>`, and hold your elements in it.

also note you cannot declare a static variable which length depends on `i`, as your example shows, you are going to need a `std::vector` or to dynamically allocate memory.

If you decide to use a `vector`, your map will be of type `map<string,vector<struct node> >`

Answer (score 0):

A map should do that for you:

```
std::map<string, struct nodo*> n_2i;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that an std::map will help here:

```
std::map< int , std::vector< struct nodo > > n;
for(int i=1;i<112;i++){
  n.insert(std::make_pair(i, std::vector<struct nodo>(111-i)));       
}
```

you could access you values after with using the index:

```
n[0].SomeProperty;
```