# Using the loop integer to define variables: c++

Tags: c++

I have a for-loop which runs over `i`. For every iteration, I wish that it creates a variable with the name `var_i` i.e if my loop runs over `i=0` to `i=4`, it should create variables like
`var_0`, `var_1`, `var_2`, `var_3` and `var_4`. How to do this in c++?

Comment: Why the -1? This question is stated clearly

Comment: OP should perhaps give us some insight into his aims so that we can give better alternatives. PS: I didn't down-vote.

Comment: I'm curious to know what you have to do with special variable names. Maybe you could paste some code to explain?

Comment: possible duplicate of [change variable name with a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968725/change-variable-name-with-a-loop)

Answer (score 3):

You can't, variable names must be known at compile-time. You can't create new variable names at run-time.

**An alternative** is to have a `std::map` or a `std::vector` if your variables are continuous.

```
std::map<int,int> int_;
std::vector<int> vint_;
vint_.resize(5);
for ( int i = 0 ; i <= 4 ; i++ )
{
   int_[i] = i;
   vint_[i] = i;
}
```

Your variables would be `int_[0]` or `vint_[0]` through `int_[4]` or `vint_[4]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create variables at runtime. Use `std:vector` instead so you'll get `var[0]`, `var[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an array of the required size and initialize it with a default value in the loop

```
int var[4];
for(int i=0; i < 4; i++){
    var[i] = 0;
}
```